# Extract strings in python

Tags: python, string, text-extraction

Basically, I want to extract the strings "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD" from a text file...

```
...... (other text goes here).....
<TD align="left" class=texttd><font class='textfont'>AAA</font></TD>
..... (useless text here).....
<TD align="left" class=texttd><font class='textfont'>BBB</font></TD>
....(more text).....
<TD align="left" class=texttd><font class='textfont'>CCC</font></TD>
<TD align="left" class=texttd><font class='textfont'>DDD</font></TD>
......(more text).....
```

I want something like if I do:-

> data = foo("file.txt")

I get:-

> data = ['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD']

What is the best possible way? My file is not big...

Basically, I want to extract "remaining upload data transfer" from [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz5PTCmbPL4aZjllZTVjMzEtZGJkNy00NzU4LThjNjktNmJiNzI4NTk4NTFi/view?hl=en) which in HTML looks like [THIS](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H5FizK11guShgm8V-R70i3_WMHtc4RBketseZhVorjY/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a REGEX but it would be "parsing" the HTML to some extent. The problem with writing regular expressions for HTML is HTML is a mess. It's rarely perfect and this causes problems when you rely on it for data.

I would personally use BeautifulSoup. It does do more than you're asking but also at superfraction of the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You want [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_file)

soup.find("font", "textfont")
```

Comment: I want to do it without using a third party library.. Bcos, I dont really want html processing.. My aim is just to extract those strings..

Comment: @shadyabhi, Not using a library is a silly goal. An HTML parser is the right tool for what you are trying to do (which is parsing HTML) and provides a way to write a simple, concise function.

Comment: @Dominic, lxml is probably a better choice these days, as it is still actively developed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
    input_file = open("myfile.txt", 'r')
    input = ''.join(input_file.readlines())

    looking_for = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
    have = []

    for thing in looking_for:
        if thing in input:
            have.append(thing)
    return have
```

Comment: I think that won't present the ordering if more than one item is present in the same line...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "ordering". I see no such specification in the question. And my algorithm will find all the strings in looking_for that are in the html, even if they are in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this it's, attempt regex for it ( which will be really had ), use a prewritten library, or do it your self with a `f = open() f.read()` and your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the data from inside all of the tags in the HTML document, while dropping all the tags themselves, you could do something like this:

```
import HTMLParser

class DataOnlyParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def parse(self, text):
        self.result = []
        self.feed(text)
        self.close()
        return self.result

    def handle_data(self, data):
        data = data.strip()
        if data:
            self.result.append(data)

p = DataOnlyParser()

data = """
<TD align="left" class=texttd><font class='textfont'>AAA</font></TD>
<TD align="left" class=texttd><font class='textfont'>BBB</font></TD>
<TD align="left" class=texttd><font class='textfont'>CCC</font></TD>
<TD align="left" class=texttd><font class='textfont'>DDD</font></TD>
"""

print p.parse(data)
# ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
```

If your selection criteria is more complex though, and/or if the input is malformed, you'd probably be better off with a library like lxml.

You do NOT want to use regular expressions to "parse" html.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).